# What is the best way the web page title having URL

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have URL defined as variable in code:

```
var s = "www.google.com";
```

What is the best way to get title of this page ?

**Updated**

Well, I understand my mistake :)  I am using meteor.js and can execute server side code.

**Updated 2**

This is bookmarking service.  An user add URL and I want to get the page title from my code.

Comment: with client-side javascript? not possible due to same-origin security policies.

Comment: As in the the text between the title tags? If so, the only way would be with serverside code.

Comment: You haven't tried anything? Like using [http.get](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http_get) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way of doing this except a remote web service. Please check out this post. http://forums.asp.net/t/1453746.aspx